# Getting undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups in my rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 4.2.5, rspec-rails 3.0.2

I want to test my API. So I created `requests` directory inside /spec. There is a file called `projects_spec.rb`

Here is the code:

```
describe 'Projects API' do
  describe 'GET /projects' do
    it 'should return 401 HTTP code' do
      get '/api/v1/projects'
      expect(response.status).to eq(401)
    end
  end
end
```

And when I run this test I'm getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProjectsAPI::GETProjects:0x007fee73ad9b48>
```

What's wrong?

```
# rails_helper.rb
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

Comment: Are you missing `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of the spec file?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti it works, but I getting TONS of warnings. Here is my stacktrace http://pastebin.com/LaYmyQEK. Also, is there a way to avoid adding require 'rails_helper' in EACH spec file. Seems it's not a DRY.

Comment: you should add `require 'rails_helper'` to each spec. Of course, you could use some metaprogramming to make sure any file under `/spec` directory has this line as first, but it is a convention to have it there

Comment: thanx, what about HUGE stacktrace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
describe 'Projects API', type: :request do
  # ...
end
```

Also, make sure you've included `require 'rails_helper'` in your `projects_spec.rb`.